# How can I get a lost of bmesh edges from a bmesh face

Tags: python

Im having trouble figuring out how to get a list of edges in a selected face.

I have this:

```
<BMFace(0x0000027AD3280CE8), index=27, totverts=3>
```

when i try to get the `.edges` of this it gives me this:

```
<BMElemSeq object at 0x0000027ABDCA10F0>
```

How can I get of BMesh Edges that make up the face?

Comment: just iterate over the face.edges... for e in face.edges: etc...

Comment: Ohh okay, I was thinking face.edges would give me a list of edges. Thanks